# How to set edgecolor same as the facecolor while drawing polygos in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, polygons

I am plotting many polygons using the command `fill`.

```
fill(X1,Y1,1)
fill(X2,Y2,2)
...
```

I want to set the edge color the same as the face color. What do I have to do for that?

I  am plotting many polygons and I need to find a way to set the edgecolor same as the facecolor. Even the facecolors are not known to me.
I have to use numbers, because I am plotting a data.

Comment: can't you just set your edge colours to none?

Comment: No, I want it same as the facecolor

Comment: but what's the difference, if it's the same as the facecolour then you won't be able to see it so you can get the same effect by just not plotting the edge colours

Comment: I know. But there is some empty space near the polygon and what I am thinking is, if I set the edgecolor to facecolor and increase the edgewidth I might be able to fill those gaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get what's wrong with the suggestion of CitizenInsane, but if you just want to save some code you could use a little helper function:

```
FillItLikeIWant = @(x,y,color) fill(x, y, color, 'EdgeColor',color)

FillItLikeIWant(x,y,'r')
```

Alternatively you can define all your "Styles" in advance, thats how I usually do it with line plots, in an array like this:

```
myStyles = {{'r','EdgeColor','r'};
            {'b','EdgeColor','b'};
            {'g','EdgeColor','g'}}
```

and then iterate through the styles:

```
for ii = 1:3
    fill(x,y,myStyles{ii}{:}); hold on
end
```

---

**Edit:**

I don't know what the single number **1** or **2** in your example `fill(X1,Y1,1)` is supposed to do, but maybe you want to create and use a colormap like this:

```
N = 500;
Cmap = colormap(jet(N));
```

Now use the helper function and every polygon gets another color of the `Cmap`.

```
for ii = 1:500
    h{ii} = FillItLikeIWant(x,y,Cmap(ii,:));
end
```

you can keep track of all colors just by the indices. Alternatively save the handles of every single polygon.
So afterwards you can get the color of a polygon by its handle:

```
get(h{500},'FaceColor')

ans =

        0.504            0            0
```

which is the same as:

```
Cmap(500,:)

ans =

        0.504            0            0
```

Comment: I need 500 different colors.

Comment: Is there any way to know the color filled in the polygon when I plot it in this way:       fill(X,Y,2)      .What color this 2 corresponds to?

Comment: what is **2** supposed to indicate? it doesn't do anything?

Answer (score 1):

Just set `EdgeColor` property/value pair, with the same color as faces:

```
t = (1/16:1/8:1)'*2*pi;
x = sin(t);
y = cos(t);
fill(x, y, 'r', 'EdgeColor', 'r');
```

Sample code for drawing multiple polygons with different colors in a for loop *(using current colormap)*:

```
function [] = foo()
%[
    cmap = colormap; % Use some colormap to have different color for polygons
    ccount = size(cmap, 1); % Number of elements in the colormap

    figure; % Create a figure
    hold on; % Avoids deleting previous polygons

    pcount = 50; % number of polygons
    for i = 1:pcount,

        % Create randomly translated polygon
        t = (1/16:1/8:1)'*2*pi;
        x = 0.1*sin(t) + rand;
        y = 0.1*cos(t) + rand;

        % Select a color in the colormap
        colorIndex = mod(i, ccount);
        if (colorIndex == 0), colorIndex = ccount; end       
        colorValue = cmap(colorIndex, :);

        % Draw the polygon
        fill(x, y, colorValue, 'EdgeColor', colorValue);

    end
%]
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I am dealing with lot of polygons and I cannot set the edge color of each polygon. I am plotting them in a loop and I need to set the edgecolor same as the facecolor in the loop itself.

Comment: @Tanuj ?! Whether `fill` is in a loop or not doesn't matter ?! ... Can you post small loop example so we can better understand what's disturbing here ??

Comment: example:

'for i = 1:100
fill(X_i, Y_i, i) 
end'

X_i is only a abbreviation for X1, X2 ...
Now I want to set the edgecolor same as facecolor.

Comment: ^^ sorry, i dont know how to add code to comments. please try to understand

Comment: Also, I know i cannot use X_i or Y_i. This is just to tell you what I am doing

Comment: @Tanuj It's truly unclear what you intend to do ... Anyway, I have updated my answer with some loop example ... Good continuation ...